# c++ class operator self-typecast

Tags: c++

How can I create an operator function within a class that serves to typecast other types as an object of that class?

e.g.

```
class MyClass
{
  // ...
    // operator ??
  // ...
}

int main()
{
  MyClass obj;
  int Somevar;
  obj=(MyClass)Somevar; // class typecast
}
```

In general, is there an operator that allows this kind of typecast in exact syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add a constructor that takes one argument:

```
class MyClass {
    explicit MyClass(int x) { … }
};
```

called as:

```
MyClass x = static_cast<MyClass>(10); // or
MyClass y = MyClass(10); // or even
MyClass z(10);
```

This allows an *explicit* cast as in your example. (The C-style cast syntax is also supported but I won’t show it here because you should **never** use C-style casts. They are evil and unnecessary.)

Sometimes (but *very* rarely), an implicit cast is more appropriate (e.g. to convert from `char*` to `std::string` in assignments). In that case, remove the `explicit` qualifier in front of the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
   MyClass(int x) { … }
};
```

Now an implicit conversion from `int` is possible:

```
MyClass a = 10;
```

However, this is usually not a good idea because implicit conversions are non-intuitive and error-prone so you should normally mark the constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: OP is using a cast.  Implicit constructor isn't necessary.  Explicit constructor would work just fine.  The text of your answer implies that they need an implicit constructor.

Comment: @Noah: wow, hadn’t noticed. You’re of course right; I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define a constructor taking `int` argument.

But implicit conversions has some problems, so many that the language has the keyword `explicit` to prohibit them.

Mainly that's about overload resolution.

So, perhaps think twice before allowing the implicit conversion.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Provide *non-explicit* constructor with argument of wanted type:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass( int x );
...
};

MyClass a = 42;
```

**Note though**: this is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the object implicitly.

```
class MyClass
{
int x;
public:
  MyClass(int X = 0):x(X){}  //also serves a default constructor
}

int main()
{
  MyClass obj = Somevar; // implicit type construction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use operator=() ?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  Myclass& operator=()(int i) {
  //do what you want
  return *this;
  }
}

int main()
{
  MyClass obj;
  int Somevar;
  obj = Somevar; // call operator=(somevar)
}
```

Comment: Because you don't want to *assign* an existing object, you want to *create* a new one. And the implicit `operator=` works fine.